# Why is my injected dependency object not the same instance in every module?

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, prism

I'm using Prism and Unity.

I've got this **bootstrapper**:

```
protected override IModuleCatalog GetModuleCatalog()
{
    ModuleCatalog catalog = new ModuleCatalog()
        .AddModule(typeof(CustomerModule.CustomerModule))
        .AddModule(typeof(EmployeesModule.EmployeesModule))
        .AddModule(typeof(MenuModule.MenuModule));
    return catalog;
}
```

And my **CustomerModule** gets a MenuManager injected and adds menu items to it:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    menuManager.MenuItems.Add("Customers");
    menuManager.MenuItems.Add("Other Customers");
}
```

But when my **MainMenuPresenter** object also gets MenuManager injected, it is not the same object:

```
public MainMenuPresenter(MainMenuView view, MenuManager menuManager)
{
    View = view;
    View.DataContext = this;

    foreach (string menuItemTitle in menuManager.MenuItems)
    {
        MenuItems.Add(menuItemTitle);
    }
}
```

**How do I tell Prism/Unity that I want the injected MenuManager to be a Singleton so that the same object is injected into each of my modules and objects?**

Comment: I wonder if I gave you a sufficient answer and if yes would you please mark it as "answer"?

Answer (score 6):

Using Unity, you do it like this (taken from [MSDN on Lifetime Managers in Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440953.aspx)):

```
// Register a type to have a singleton lifetime without mapping the type
// Uses the container only to implement singleton behavior
myContainer.RegisterType<MySingletonObject>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
// Following code will return a singleton instance of MySingletonObject
// Container will take over lifetime management of the object
myContainer.Resolve<MySingletonObject>();
```